# create table using case when clause and log function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table profit:

```
date    name    percentage 
xxx      yyy      10
xxd      ddd     -10
...
```

I want to create a new table by log(percentage)

```
date    name    percentage  logP
xxx      yyy      10        xxx
xxd      ddd     -10        xxx
```

Here is my code:

```
create table logProfit as
Select a.*,
case when a.percentage=0 then NULL 
when a.percentage=-100 then NULL
when a.percentage<0 and a.percentage > -100 then -log(10,a.percentage)
else log(10,a.percentage) end  logP
from profit a;
```

But it has error like

```
"SQL error: ORA-01428: '-8.2272727272727272727272727272727272727' out of arrange
01428. 00000 -  "argument '%s' is out of range",
```

is my case when clause wrong please?

Comment: I think log function receives two parameters, maybe this is causing the error

Comment: Thanks for reply. By default, it should be natural log.

Comment: Are you going to show us the error?

Comment: Ahh, i see. However this `SELECT LOG(10) FROM DUAL;` gives me `ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments`, maybe i'm wrong

Comment: Thanks for all your reply. I add 10 in log and update with error message. It is strange though. In the oracle link below, it shows that you can have only 1 parameter then it will use natural log. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2014.htm#OLADM590

Comment: That's the Oracle OLAP reference, the SQL reference shows two required parameters: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions080.htm#i84140

Comment: Thanks all. I add 10 into log function. But it says -8.227 is out of range. But I already consider it in my case when clause. why please?

Comment: What data type is your percentage column?

Comment: It is float from -100 to 100

Comment: `But it says -8.227 is out of range. But I already consider it in my case when clause` You're not actually considering it in your case statement. Only the case of -100 is considered. But `LOG()` accepts only values > 0. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/log.php Incidentally, if you want the natural log use `LN()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a log of a negative number, which you're trying to handle with this case:

```
when a.percentage<0 and a.percentage > -100 then -log(10,a.percentage)
```

But you have the minus sign in the wrong place; or perhaps you want two. At the moment if your float percentage value is -8.227... you're still evaluating:

```
log(10, -8.227)
```

which gets `ORA-01428: argument '-8.227' is out of range`, before you can negate it. So you need to negate the percentage inside the function call too; either:

```
when a.percentage<0 and a.percentage > -100 then log(10,-a.percentage)
```

or

```
when a.percentage<0 and a.percentage > -100 then -log(10,-a.percentage)
```

which for the simpler percentage -8.227 would give you .915241497 or -.915241497 respectively.

---

Incidentally, you could simplify your logic a bit by using the [`sign()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions164.htm) and the [the `abs()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions009.htm) to handle the negative numbers; then you only need to explicitly deal with zero:

```
sign(a.percentage) * log(10,
  case when a.percentage != 0 then abs(a.percentage) else null end)
```

Or if you think it's necessary, to deal with -100; not really sure why that's treated as a special case though:

```
sign(a.percentage) * log(10,
  case when a.percentage != 0 and a.percentage > -100
    then abs(a.percentage) else null end)
```

Quick demo for comparison:

```
with profit as (
  select cast(-100 as float) as percentage from dual
  union all select -0.5 from dual
  union all select 0 from dual
  union all select 0.5 from dual
  union all select 100 from dual
)
Select a.*,
  case when a.percentage=0 then NULL 
    when a.percentage=-100 then NULL
    when a.percentage<0 and a.percentage > -100 then -log(10,-a.percentage)
    else log(10,a.percentage) end as orig_logP,
  sign(a.percentage) * log(10,
    case when a.percentage != 0 and a.percentage > -100
      then abs(a.percentage) else null end) as new_logP
from profit a;

PERCENTAGE  ORIG_LOGP   NEW_LOGP
---------- ---------- ----------
      -100
       -.5 .301029996 .301029996
         0
        .5    -.30103    -.30103
       100          2          2
```

Or as David Faber pointed out, if you really want the natural log, use [the `ln()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions090.htm):

```
sign(a.percentage) * ln(case when a.percentage != 0 and a.percentage > -100
    then abs(a.percentage) else null end) as logP
```

which gets:

```
PERCENTAGE       LOGP
---------- ----------
      -100
       -.5 .693147181
         0
        .5 -.69314718
       100 4.60517019
```